# Why I can't assign chrome.storage data to vuex state?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, vuex, google-chrome-storage

I've chrome extension which set chrome.storage.sync in content-scripts, and I need to get this data in popup and assign it to vuex state property.
Below is how I was trying to do this.

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    data: null //chrome data store
  },
  mutations: {
    setData(state){
      chrome.storage.sync.get('igHelperStore', (chromeStorage) => { 
        state.data = chromeStorage;
      });
    },
  },
  actions: {
  },
  getters: {
    getData: state => state.data.igHelperStore,
    getFollowedProfiles: state => state.data.igHelperStore.following.followedProfiles,
  },
  modules: {
    appearance,
    app
  }
})
```

Update:
And below not working too

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    data: null //chrome data store
  },
  mutations: {
    setData(state, data){
      state.data = data;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    setData(context) {
      chrome.storage.sync.get('testStore', (chromeStorage) => { 
        context.dispatch('setData', chromeStorage);
      });
    }
  },
  getters: {},
  modules: {}
})
```

Comment: And what goes wrong exactly?

Comment: state.data is undefined if I want to print it in console. Of course on popup init I run setData mutation.

Comment: Probably the issue is that `chrome.storage.sync` is async, whereas mutations should be synchronous.

Comment: Okay Alex so, is there any solution for do it?

Comment: move async code to an action and pass result to a mutation

Comment: @Anatoly I tried to do this in this way https://pastebin.com/CFPFF8YV but it looks like not working.

Comment: Use  context.commit('setData', chromeStorage); instead of  context.dispatch('setData', chromeStorage);